# Перегрузка оператора приведения типа

Tags: c++, исключения, перегрузка-операторов

Мне необходимо при приобразовании указателя на объект класса А в указатель на объект класса B выдавать exception,но компилятор не позволяет перегрузку

```
 #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    class A
    {
        protected:
            int a;
        public:
            A operator B*()(A *ax) //Тут выдает ошибку,говорит,что B не имя типа
            {
                throw("Bad Type Overload");
            }
    };
    class B:public A
    {
     protected:
        int B;
    };
    int main()
    {
        A *a;
        B *b;
        b=(B*)a;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: а он вообще знает что такое класс B? может попробовать через class указать что это именно класс? И да, а вы уверены что это нормально когда родитель знает о наследнике?

Comment: @pavel Ну,тут он и не должен знать о наследнике,он только должен знать,что приводиться к тому типу

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что что такое B, в строке с оператором неизвестно.

Далее, оператор приведения не имеет возвращаемого типа (он уже указан в операторе!), и не получает никакого параметра - он уже получает `this`...

Член `int B;` в классе `B` тоже не есть хорошо.

Приведение `b=(B*)a` не будет даже пытаться использовать ваш оператор - потому что это приведение указателя к указателю (в скобках - ужасное: указателя на базовый класс к указателю на производный...)

Так что лучшее, что вы можете получить - примерно

```
class B;

class A
{
    protected:
        int a;
    public:
        operator B*()
        {
            throw("Bad Type Overload");
        }
};
class B:public A
{
 protected:
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    A *a;
    (B*)*a;
    return 0;
}
```

но это все - не очень здоровое занятие, и непонятно кому и зачем нужное...

**Update**
Вот, взгляните - исключение вы можете получить, но при приведении ссылок.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() {}
};


int main()
{
    Base * b = new Base;
    Derived * d = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(b);
    cout << d << endl;

    try {
        Base bb;
        Derived & dd = dynamic_cast<Derived &>(bb);
    } catch(exception&e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Просто у меня задание состоит в этом,нужно обработать исключение,когда указатель базового класса приводиться к указателю на наследника,я вот и подумал,что тут через перегрузку нужно делать

Comment: @andybelous2 даже так можно привести будет. http://ideone.com/maTeIf

Comment: Как тогда поступить?Так как мне необходимо именно преобразование указателя к указателю

Comment: @pavel не выдает exception так

Comment: Указатель к указателю исключения не даст, только `nullptr`. Даст исключение ссылку к ссылке - при использовании `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: См. дополненный ответ

Comment: В задании сказано,что класс B-производный класса А и что мне нужно определить обработчик исключительной ситуации при приобразовании указателя базового класса в указатель производного класса,ссылки не подойдут,думаю

Comment: Обработчик определить-то можно, только вот исключение кто генерировать будет?...

Comment: @andybelous2: Какая-либо перегрузка операторов в С++ возможна тоолько для class- и enum-типов, по каковой причине никакого перехватчика/обработчика преобразования именно *указателей* вы сделать не сможете. Нет в С++ такой фичи. Не ясно, кто вам придумал такое задание.